# Prove or disprove $B\setminus B^{\prime}=f\left(A\setminus A^{\prime}\right)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's assume $A$ and $B$ are two discrete sets, and  $A^{\prime}$ and $B^{\prime}$ are their subsets (i.e. $A^{\prime}\subseteq A$ and $B^{\prime}\subseteq B$). We have a mapping  $f$ from $A$ to $B$ (i.e. $f:A\rightarrow B$).

If $B=f\left(A\right)$ and $B^{\prime}=f\left(A^{\prime}\right)$ hold, can we prove or disprove $B\setminus B^{\prime}=f\left(A\setminus A^{\prime}\right)$ ?

Comment: What kind of mapping is $f$?

Comment: That's wrong if $f$ is not injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through the logic and make a proof/counterexample, and maybe put in a stronger statement.

Let $x \in (B - B')$. Because $x \in B$, $x=f(y)$ for some $y \in A$. However, $x \notin B'$, so there is no $z$ such that $f(z)=x$ and $z \in A'$. Hence it follows that $y \in A - A'$, so it is true that $B-B' \subset f(A - A')$.

Let $x \in f(A - A')$. Then there is some $y \in A - A'$ such that $f(y)=x$. Of course, $y \in A$, hence $x = f(y) \in B$. Furthermore, $y \notin A'$, but this **does not rule not** $x \in B'$, because there could be some other $z$ such that $f(z)=x$! Thus, injectivity will ensure that there is no other such $z$, hence $f(A-A') = B - B'$ if and only if $f$ is injective.

Take a constant function on the real line, say $f\equiv 0$. Now, let $A=\mathbb{R}$ and $A'=\mathbb{R}^+$. Then $B'=f(A')=\{0\}=f(A)=B$, so $B'-B=\phi$, however $f(A-A') = \{ 0\}$, and they are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

Consider an example $A=\{0,1\}$, $A'=\{1\}$, $B=B'=\{1\}$, and $f(0)=f(1)=1$. What can you conclude??